# Shared email acct - how to move sent mail from all users to shared "sent items"

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, outlook

I've set up a shared email account at Exchange, which several users have access to, as a secondary mailbox (along with their personal mailbox)

I would like to know if the following is possible

- all replies and/or mail created when "in" the shared account, is sent from the shared account
- all sent mail end up in the sent mail folder of the shared account, not the individual users sent mail folders
- users can set custom signatures when sending mail from the shared account

Is this possible to accomplish with Exchange 2007/Outlook, using server and/or clientside rules?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can use these utilities:
1) RightFrom
2) UniSent
Just google for them.

Regards,
Victor

Answer (score 3):

What I gather you're asking for is that the Outlook client change the "from" field of email replies to match the mailbox that the user is currently using.  I'm guessing that if this is possible, it will involve custom forms and some coding.

Short of that, it may be easier to have people access the shared mailbox via OWA (extending the automatic timeout to something more leisurely), and log in as the shared user, to achieve your goal.

Users can access the 2nd mailbox using only their personal credentials like so:

- log into OWA normally
- click their username in the upper right-hand corner
- enter the friendly name of the mailbox to which they have access (it will open in a new window)
- You can then copy & keep the URL to the target mailbox - mine's in the form of https://domainname.com/owa/other-mailbox@domainname.com/
- the user will be able to use their personal credentials at the login screen, but it will open the alternate mailbox

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, I do not want people to have access/passwords to other accounts than their own. I just want to grant rights to view/send as the shared acct. Is it possible to view other mailboxes than your own with OWA?

Comment: Absolutely.  Edited it in above.  We use this a lot, as some of our shared mailboxes are *massive* and create a lot of churning on both ends for remote users when they try to cache a mailbox copy in the thick Outlook client.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It works. However, I've noticed that all users get the same signature when sending from OWA. Is it not possible to have per-mailbox, per-user signatures using this method? This is what we have today, using IMAP for shared mail accts (which works but have problems of its own, which is why we'd like to migrate to exchange...)

Comment: Glad that helped.  You can customize OWA, but I've never gone farther than sticking in a company logo.  ;)  There should be some programmatic way to handle this based on the currently used credentials (even if it's just a client-side add-on or script), but that's about where my knowhow runs out.